# Windows telnet gives different result

Tags: php, linux, windows, telnet

I try to implement this [source](http://paparadit.blogspot.co.id/2012_07_01_archive.html) and runs good.
And when i try to reach it from my telnet(windows), it always send my typed character like this.
[image]
But when i try to access it using linux, it works perfect.
did i get something wrong using windows cmd?
BTW i use this `telnet 127.0.0.1 12345` to connect via telnet on both OS.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft telnet sends characters immediately on a keypress, whereas Linux telnet has a 'line buffer' and sends no data until a newline (enter key) is pressed.
If you want to send character commands via windows telnet, you have to use the 'send' command.

1. Open telnet and connect to your server
2. Press Control+] to go into command mode
3. Type `send <message>` where  is the string you want to send to the server.

Alternatively, you can use a third party telnet client, e.g. 'PuTTY'

Comment: i'm sory maybe my question is not so clear, but what really happen is i cant even type "quit" and press enter,.
because it will send q immidiately.

Comment: thankyou, it gets me one step closer, but actually i cant get response from server.
here is the result
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'


Microsoft Telnet> send hallo
Sent string hallo
Microsoft Telnet>

Comment: Just press 'enter' in command mode to go back to the output and you'll see your server's response.

Comment: i was facing the issue of sending character typed in the command line and microsoft telnet sending them immediately. `Ctrl+]` saved my night :)